# Backbone Association not working with fetch

Tags: backbone.js, nested, associations

I am using Backbone-Associations from 
github-Backbone associations
https://github.com/dhruvaray/backbone-associations
for nested models to work with backnone.

I am getting an error while calling fetch() on a model. the response json from server exactly matches the model definitions. i cant figure out what i am missing...

Versions:

Backbone: 0.9.2

Backbone-associations: 0.2.0

**TypeError: this.attributes[relationKey].off is not a function
this.attributes[relationKey].off("all");**

```
//this is the code i am using..

var ProductVariation = Backbone.AssociatedModel.extend({
    defaults: {
        ImageUrl:'',
        Desc:''
    }
});

var Product = Backbone.AssociatedModel.extend({
    relations: [{
        type: Backbone.Many,
        key: 'ProductVariations',
        relatedModel: ProductVariation
    }],
    url: '/GetProductById',
    defaults: {
        CategoryId: 0,
        ProductVariations: [],
        Summary: ''
    }
});
```

am i missing something? any help appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

Oops it's my mistake...

Actually I was using an old version of BackboneJS, but thinking that I was using the latest..
Which doesn't have `off` and `on` methods on a collection, instead they use `bind` and `unbind` respectively.

Replacing the old one with new one is the fix.